# Block imports for some scripts in __init__.py

Tags: python, import, lib

Is it possible to block imports o library for the specified files?
Let's say I have 2 scripts:`/path/to/script/1/script.py` and `/path/to/script/2/script.py`. In both I would like to import some `lib.py`.
Is it possible to write `__init.py__` so it would block importing library for the first script but not for a second one?

Comment: It might be possible using AST but the bigger question is why would you do it?

Comment: I'm adding a module to repository but we want to limit use of that module only to some scripts. I'm looking for a solution to avoid accidental use of that module by other people in the scripts other than those few files.